# Creating a new project using NPX giving error "ENOENT", any solutions?

Tags: npm, next.js, npm-install, npx

I am running
npx create-next-app@latest but it is giving me an error.

```bash
D:\WEB\roleready>npx create-next-app@latest
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path C:\Windows\System32\'C:
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Windows\System32\'C:'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\kisho\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-02-10T12_30_06_201Z-debug-0.log


I tried clearing npm cache and reinstalling NodeJS but still not happening anything.
```